# Difference between fill color and background color

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa, winapi

I am porting an application from Windows to Mac OS X. Here, I have one confusion between the use of different terms.

On Windows, we use `SetBkColor` to set background color of a device context.

On Mac OS X, there is `setFill` to set fill color.

Is there any difference between this background color of Windows and fill color of Mac OS X?

For stroke clear (by `setStroke`), I think on Windows, same effect is achieved by `CreatePen` for lines and `SetTextColor` for texts. Is this concept is okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both native Windows development and Core Graphics on iOS/Mac OS use the so called 'painter's model' of drawing.  Just like actual painting, you select a color for your pen or brush and everything you draw, fill, what-have-you from that point until you change it will use that color.  On the Mac, more specifically, you set stroke for such things as text and borders, and fills for methods that fill.  You have to set each separately as each accomplishes something different.

SetBkColor would be different because it fills into the background, on Mac or iOS, you would instead set the fill color and then use a drawing method to fill a rect -- and usually this would all be done by overriding a view's drawRect method.  For example, here's one way to do that:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef myContext = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];

   // ********** Your drawing code here **********
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 1, 0, 0, 1);  // set my 'brush color'
   CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 200, 100 ));  // fill it

   CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0, 0, 1, .5);  // set my brush color
   CGContextFillRect (myContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, 100, 200));  //fill it
}
```

Drawing is done back to front, so, if you wanted to set the background to a certain color, you would simply make that the first operation and fill the full window/view rectangle with whatever color you like.

Have a look at the Quartz 2D drawing guide for further examples.  If you are coming from Windows, you will find Quartz/Core Graphics to have a very comparable, and in my mind richer, set of drawing capabilities. (The above example is from this guide)

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html